# Unexpected result while sorting the csv file

Tags: linux, sort

I have the following CSV file as shown below with 4 columns, and I am taking input of filename from bash terminal.

```
Sile,Barhams,Female,sba3@exe.com
Shae,Scotti,Male,mi5@exe.com
Shae,Bonham,Female,sm9@ex.org
Shay,Ert,Female,sep@emple.gov
Simeon,Dearle,Male,sz@e.net
```

Desired output is:

```
Shae,Male
Shae,Female
Shay,Female
Sile,Female
Simeon,Male
```

Now I tried following code snippets and got the result as shown :

```
cat $file | cut -d, -f1,3 | sort -k 1,1 -s

Shae,Female
Shae,Male
Shay,Female
Sile,Female
Simeon,Male

cat $file  | cut -d, -f1,3 | sort -k 1,1 -s -n

Sile,Female
Shae,Male
Shae,Female
Shay,Female
Simeon,Male
```

Can somebody explain my both snippets and how I can get desired one please, according to me for first code I am sorting according to first column and in case of tie I have specified stable sort to get the desired output but IDK what is the issue and in second code I wonder how "Sile" appears on the top.

Comment: If supported by your `sort` implementation, the `--debug` option will likely be of help.

Comment: Please tell me what changes i need to do for getting desired output... I need help as ai tried all sort of possible combinations of flags of sort

Comment: thnx @fra-san infact -t, worked but I would request you that how it worked ? and moreover explain my pipeline of both code that I stated above as a new answer please it will improve my understanding.

Comment: ah, indeed, I missed the thing with the two `Shae`'s switching order the first time. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cat $file | cut -d, -f1,3 | sort -k 1,1 -s

Shae,Female
Shae,Male
Shay,Female
Sile,Female
Simeon,Male
```

You get that because the fields `-k` refers to are the *blank separated* fields by default and `Shae,Female` sorts before `Shae,Male`.

You need the `-t` option to tell it to use the comma as a separator instead:

> `-t`, `--field-separator=SEP`
> use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition

```
$ cat "$file"  | cut -d, -f1,3 | sort -t, -k 1,1 -s
Shae,Male
Shae,Female
Shay,Female
Sile,Female
Simeon,Male
```

---

```
cat $file  | cut -d, -f1,3 | sort -k 1,1 -s -n

Sile,Female
Shae,Male
Shae,Female
Shay,Female
Simeon,Male
```

Here, with `-n`, the sorting is based on the numerical value of the data. But you don't have a numeric strings here: all non-numeric strings will be treated as zeroes. Hence, effectively no primary sorting rule. With `-s`, the order will be left as-is. Without `-s`, `sort` will fall back to a textual sort to get *some* result.

Answer (score 1):

Strange. When I apply your pipeline to that data, I get

```
Sile
Shae
Shae
Shay
Simeon
```

Let's have a closer look at the pipeline:

```
cat filename | grep "^.\{0\}S" | cut -d, -f1,6 | sort -s -n -k1,1
```

First, simplify it to

```
grep "^S" filename | cut -d, -f1,6 | sort -s -n -k1,1
```

You don't need the cat (it's sometimes called "cat abuse"), and the regular expression asks for zero characters after the beginning of a line, followed by S. This is equivalent to a line that starts with S.

Why do you cut out fields 1 and 6 when there are only two fields? And I don't believe that the result keeps the second field. Something is not right here, but let's ignore the strange `cut`.

You perform a numerical sort. Since there is no number in the file and `-s` is specified, the order remains as it is. Remove the `-n` and/or the `-s`.

Comment: In particular, it's the combination of numeric and stable that gives the result that nothing happens. Without `-s`, it would sort the lines with equal numerical value (i.e. all) based on  the text order (well, my `sort` does).

Comment: I modified question please now do the needful and I would request to remove previous comments so to have have more clear answer.

Comment: The first snippet has the desired result. My answer explains why. I can't explain the `cat`, though.